# Getting "Unable to open nested compressed entry" when making use of WarLauncher for executing a war file outside of servlet container

Tags: spring, jar, war, executable-jar, spring-boot

I am implementing a war file which should support execution in two different ways:

1. Inside Servlet Container - by deploying it in Tomcat or Jetty.
2. Outside Servlet Container - executing it from command prompt and not using any embedded servlet container. This is required to be supported as part of the war file.

I found Spring Boot Loader component more relevant for fulfilling #2. I tried using it manually before integrating it with Maven. I followed the section - 'WAR file structure' as mentioned as per [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader) documentation. Refer to section 'WAR file structure'.

I followed the following steps. I created the war file. I unzipped it and then added all the spring boot loader class files at its root. I added appropriate entries to the manifest file for making the war executable. Then zipped it and renamed back it back to the original war file. When I executed it with command - Java -jar mywar.war, it failed with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested compressed entry WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:79)
```

It is giving error not only for specific jar but for all jar files. I guess, it will also fail when I automate the above steps with Maven.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some restrictions with the underlying ZIP file format that make it impossible for the `WarLauncher` (and friends) to load resources from nested *compressed* archives. However you were building your WAR file you would need to re-do that step and ensure that the nested JARs are not compressed. Then it should work. (And if you use default settings for a Maven WAR build it would also work.)

Comment: Is it because I am doing manual unzip and zip? Will it work if I add loader classes during prepackage phase while creating a war file? How do I fix it manually?

Comment: How did you create the WAR file? It's the JAR files in `WEB-INF/lib` that are causing problems. Probably whatever tool you used to create those entries has an option to *not* compress them?

Comment: I used windows 7 provided compression and did not used any tool as such. It does not provide with any GUI where you specify not to compress.

Comment: Now, I am trying with Maven. It is complaining that artifact not found. Is group and artifact id for boot loader correct. The xml is huge for this comment. Need to open a different question for it.

Comment: Windows native ZIP tools are pretty rubbish. If you need to do this manually you could try a different tool (like 7Zip perhaps). Why do you need to do it manually though? Wouldn't it be easier to use Maven to build your WAR?

Comment: I implemented it through maven and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AnandPatel, Can you send you pom.xml?